# OpenCL converting from cl_program to cl::program

Tags: c++, opencl

I've been working on an OpenCL project using the C++ bindings and now need to use external code which is written using the C OpenCL bindings. To convert C++ OpenCL variables to C I've used the `()` operator but can't seem to find inverse of this. The variable I need to convert is `cl_program` to `cl::Program`.

```
// calling C OpenCL function with cpp member variables
cl_program programc = aocl_utils::func(m_context(), binary_file.c_str(), &device(), 0);
// converting programc back to C++ OpenCL
cl::Program program(&programc); // this doesn't work
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. You can't name a variable `something::Something` in C++. `::` is a scope operator in C++. This means the `Something` is part of a namespace or a class. Please provide some code.

Comment: Please check this link http://github.khronos.org/OpenCL-CLHPP/classcl_1_1_program.html

Comment: @RawN I've added more details to the question include code. Thanks S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the object using the constructor.

```
cl::Program::Program    (   const Context &     context,
                            const vector< Device > &    devices,
                            const Binaries &    binaries,
                            vector< cl_int > *  binaryStatus = NULL,
                            cl_int *    err = NULL 
                        )
```

Or use this constructor to convert from cl_program.

```
cl::Program::Program    (   const cl_program &  program,
                            bool    retainObject = false 
                         )
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I'm fine with the basic constructor for Program but want to convert a cl_program to a cl::program as in the code now in the question. Thanks S

Comment: replace cl::Program program(&programc); with cl::Program program(programc);